# How to use visio 2010

Tags: microsoft-visio

When drawing a bridge you have to insert the measurements and make arrows etc to reference the bridge. I need to know how to do this.  Also is there any step by step instructions for visio 2010? Something that goes over the tool bar and other things we need to know?

Answer (score 0):

Here's two very basic starter guides to Visio 2010 from Microsoft's website.

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/A-beginner-s-guide-to-Visio-2010-88d2a308-7283-4981-839d-86e2aca8c456

> Add text to shapes
>
> 1. Click the shape and start typing.
> 2. When you finish typing, click on a blank area of the drawing page or press ESC.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Basic-tasks-in-Visio-2010-2bfdf03f-4cb1-4dc5-a2a4-c0494f37e544

> Add text to the page
>
> 1. On the Home tab, in the Tools group, click the Text tool.
> 2. Click an empty area of the page. A text box appears.
> 3. Type the text that you want.
> 4. On the Home tab, in the Tools group, click Pointer Tool to stop using the Text tool.
>
> The text box now has the characteristics of other shapes. You can select it and type to change the text, you can drag it to another part of the page, and you can format the text by using the Font and Paragraph groups on the Home tab. In addition, when you hold the pointer over the text, AutoConnect arrows appear so you can connect the text to other shapes.

I suggest searching youtube for video demonstrations of more functionality in Visio 2010, to really see the step-by-step process for creating diagrams.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Thanks David. The entire page has content that the initial poster is looking for, but I've added some quotes to point out the text parts.